# How many linear independent vector fields can be constructed on a general manifold with $\chi(M)=0$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology

We have known how many linear independent vector fields can be constructed on $S^n$:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_fields_on_spheres

So how many linear independent vector fields can be constructed on a general other manifold with $\chi(M)=0$? Is there any progress on this area?

Comment: There's a bound coming from computing Stiefel-Whitney classes. It should imply that in general you can only get one.

Comment: This is called the *span* of the manifold $M$, and is well studied since the 1960s.